# What adjective describes "an offer which other party can't refuse"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Godfather movie has a famous dialogue-

> Make me an offer, I can't refuse.

I am reading a book of economics, and often there is mention of exchange and barter.

> A trade goes through, when buyer makes a **convincing??** offer to the seller.

Convincing is just place holder here. What adjective would be appropriate here in place of convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Irresistible** describes something that cannot be resisted.

**Unrefusable** likewise describes something that cannot be refused. However, this could imply that there is some coercion or lack of choice, whereas 'irresistible' means that you can't refuse because it is such an attractive offer.

There are other [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/irresistible) of 'irresistible' but none seem to carry the same weight. They more just describe an *attractive* offer but don't necessarily suggest that it is inevitable one would accept it.