# what verb/adjective would describe clickbait headline

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Clickbaits headline are a norm these days. If I have to describe the meaning of clickbait, what verb/adjective should I use?

> The headline was seductive.

> The headline was tempting.

> The headline was appealing.

Comment: At the moment this can only attract opinion-based answers. All three of those words fit well, and it would be a matter of personal choice. Can you say a bit more about what you are trying to say? Also, whilst not a duplicate, you may want to consider this recent question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314958/what-adjective-describes-an-offer-which-other-party-cant-refuse/314967#314967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"attention-grabbing headline" is the most common trope used in marketing and journalism.

The headline was attention grabbing. [notice, no hyphen when it is not adjectival]

Another is **catchy**:
That headline is very catchy.